# NoMethodError name RoR user.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

Followed the tutorial at [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/magical-authentication-sorcery/)

for a simple sorcery app. I am receiving undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

migration

```
class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email,            :null => false
      t.string :crypted_password
      t.string :salt

      t.timestamps                :null => false
    end

    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

/home/david/Magical/app/views/user_mailer/activation_needed_email.html.erb

```
<p>Welcome, <%= @user.name %>!</p>

<p>To login to the site, just follow <%= link_to 'this link', 
activate_user_url$

<p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
```

users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, email_format: { message: 'has 
  invalid format'
End
```

Comment: Users controller. (source) https://github.com/bodrovis/SitePoint-Sorcery/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the long way home and cloned the Github repo. At first I was getting a 'stack level too deep' error, but I found that the gemfile loaded rails 4.2.1 .
I changed this to 4.2.10 and all went well after the migrations and minor tweaks in the tutorial.
along the way, I found rails_db gem which is a great simple gem for working with sqLite. [rails_db gem](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db)